# Using the package keyword in a java program run on the Command Prompt

Tags: java, package, command-prompt, keyword

I am an intermediate Java programmer, but I have only had experience using IDEs such as NetBeans to write and run my programs.  I recently began writing my programs in text editors to run my programs through the Command Prompt for Windows 10.

I succeeded in creating a HelloWorld program using the Command Prompt, but am troubled by how I got it to work.

Originally my code was:

```
package helloworld;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
```

I saved this as a .java file in the directory C:\projects\myprojects\helloworld.

Then I typed the following commands in the Command Prompt:

```
cd C:\projects\myprojects\helloworld
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jkd1.8.0_121\bin
javac HelloWorld.java
java -cp . helloworld.HelloWorld
```

Which resulted in the error:

Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld

However, once I recompiled my code omitting the first line

```
package.helloworld;
```

the program ran as expected.

Why was the Command Prompt not able to find my class when the first line was present.  I tried to change the directory to simply C:\projects\myprojects, but that failed as well.  How can I successfully write a program with the

```
package helloworld;
```

line included?

Comment: The package is part of the classes fully-qualified name. After compiling, `cd ..` and `java -cp . helloworld.HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

As [Elliott answered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) comment, the packages are a part of class fully-qualified name. You can test it using

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

to print out the **current class name including package**.

To answer your question however you have to do either:
1- `cd ..` and then `java -cp . helloworld.HelloWorld`
or
2- `java helloworld\HelloWorld`

Might want to refer to [this](https://coderanch.com/t/592115/java/Explanation-java-cp-command) as a `java -cp` detailed example.

Comment: Was missing the cd .. command. Not entirely sure what that was but seems to be the root cause of the error. Thx

Comment: That will [moves you up one directory](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Directories-in-Command-Prompt).

Answer (score 0):

To run any class which is a part of a a package from command prompt, you're current directory needs to be the base directory of the project.

Then you can refer to all classes within that project using their reference i.e. fully qualified class name(FQCN).

eg.
If I have a class with the :

location -  C:\myProj\org\myproj\ExampleClass.java
FQCN - org.myproj.ExampleClass.

I would be doing the following :

```
cd C:\myproj
javac org\myproj\ExampleClass.java
java -cp . org.myproj.ExampleClass
```

This is assuming that the java bin folder has already been added to the Path environment variable.